# How can I forward a port to another computer but maintain the originating IP?

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking

I need to forward traffic coming into a cloud-provisioned Ubuntu VPS at 1.1.1.100 on port 1234 to port 5678 on local Windows computer (192.168.0.200, which is behind a router at 2.2.2.200 / 192.168.0.1), but to preserve the originating IP address. The router forwards port 5678 to the Windows machine.

When I run this on the VPS:

> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT
>   --to-destination 2.2.2.200:5678 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 2.2.2.200 --dport 5678 -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.100

This works to forward the packets, but the server at 2.2.2.200 thinks everything is coming from 1.1.1.100. The originating IP is lost.

Question 1: can I accomplish what I need with just iptables on the VPS? (I think the answer is No, but I'd love to be wrong.)

Question 2: can I manipulate iptables and/or routes on the router at 2.2.2.200 to accomplish this? What do I need to add to the router's iptables, and what do I need to change in the VPS's iptables?

Comment: Why are you doing SNAT here?

Comment: You'll have to use a tunnel because 1.1.1.100 is not in the path between the random client and the windows system.

Comment: Would the SNAT work if I told the router to route all traffic from 192.168.0.200 back to 1.1.1.100?